# Manipulating a variable in one object also manipulates another object in R

Tags: r, variables, data.table

I am creating a copy of an object, and then when I manipulate the copy, also the original is changed. Is anyone familiar with this?

Reproducible example -

```
a <- data.table(av = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), bv = rnorm(5))

b <- a

b[, av:=factor(av)]

str(a) # av is a factor...
```

R version 4.2.0

data.table 1.14.2

Comment: I can reproduce it, but don't know the answer. In that way it won't get manipulated. 
  library(data.table)
    a <- data.table(av = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), bv = rnorm(5))
    
    b <- a
    
    b<- b[, as.factor(av)]
    
    str(a)
    str(b)

Comment: You're not creating a copy of the data but just another name for the same data. So, `b` is just a shallow copy and not a deep one. data.table package modifies the data by reference and that's why what you call _copy_ also gets modified. If you want a (deep) copy of the data, you should use `b <- copy(a)` after loading data.table package.